# Show bounty details in the mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bounties

I use the mobile SE app a lot; it is my primary access to SE. So, what bugs me is that when I find a question with a bounty, all we get is this:
[image: Mobile SE]

Which is compared to users of browsers, who see this:
[image: Web/PC SE]

Although not much more detail in this case, it still has more; unlike on mobile, Browser users can see **why** the bounty was set, along with the comment from the bounty-setter. Why can't we have this as a feature in Mobile SE?